# Performance Way to check if a byte array contains another byte Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization

I'm checking if an byte array contains a another Byte Array with this Code:

```
private int IndexOf(int index, byte[] AllBytes, byte[] searchByteArray)
{
    for (int i = index; i <= AllBytes.Length - 1 - searchByteArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= searchByteArray.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (AllBytes[i + j] == searchByteArray[j])
            {
                if (j + 1 == searchByteArray.Length)
                    return i;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That works perfect and I get the index of the first byte back.

But the problem is I want to check very large Data.

My "big" Array contains around 900000000 Bytes and my searchArray about 10-20 Bytes. In that way my function is very very slow. Is there a way to make a better performance?

Thanks.

Comment: This is too broad here at SO, so I think your are better of at [codereview.se] with such question.

Comment: There are many ways. It's a [string search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm), and there are several different algorithms for that with different trade-offs.

Answer (score 2):

You could adapt the [Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) to bytes.

First, you create an array `int[256]` where the array indexes correspond to all possible byte values. The array contains the positions of each byte value in the search pattern starting from the end, and the search pattern length for values not appearing in the search pattern.

Then you compare the last position of the pattern with a position in the input array. If the values do not match, you can advance the search position by the value in the table found at the index equal to the value in the input array. If they match, compare the pattern with the input.

Example

```
intput:         100 206 002 250 123 075 074 109 184 222
search pattern:             200 109 100 150 123
                                             ^
                                             |
```

The table

```
...
[108] = 5
[109] = 3
[110] = 5
...
```

the value `123` does not match `109`, therefore you look up the table at position `109` and get `3`. I.e. you can increase the search position by `3`, so that the two `109` values line up. If the value was `108`, you could have moved by `5` positions (the full search pattern length).

The link above explains the algorithm in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar.  What I needed to do was determine if an array of bytes is present within a different array of bytes.  I did not need to know how many times one array appeared within the other array or even the position.

My search for a quick solution which performs well didn't yield any acceptable results.  I've seen the Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm as well as other supposedly fast search algorithms suggested as answers to virtually every question on the subject I found yet I have been unable to find a single implementation of one of those algorithms which is actually faster than unoptimized brute code.

So I decided to go with brute force since the code is vastly superior than the Boyer–Moore implementations.  Being a little on the obsessive side I did make a few basic optimizations to the brute force approach.  I present it here for others who happen upon this in the future.

In my testing my optimizations resulted in code which executes very close to 100% faster when tested against purely pseudo-random data.  My code is not designed to allow you to find all the occurrences of one array within another but it can be easily modified to do so.  I'll leave that to the reader.

My code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether a byte array contains the specified sequence of bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="caller">The byte array to be searched.</param>
    /// <param name="array">The byte to be found.</param>
    /// <returns>The first location of the sequence within the array, -1 if the sequence is not found.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    public static int Contains(this byte[] caller, byte[] array)
    {
        byte startValue, endValue;
        int result, arrayLength, searchBoundary, j, startLocation, endOffset;

        if (caller == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(caller)}");
        if (array == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(array)}");
        if (caller.Length == 0 || array.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Argument {(caller.Length == 0 ? nameof(caller) : nameof(array))} is empty.");

        if (array.Length > caller.Length)
            return -1;

        startValue = array[0];
        arrayLength = array.Length;

        if (arrayLength > 1)
        {
            result = -1;
            endValue = array[^1];
            endOffset = arrayLength - 1;
            searchBoundary = caller.Length - arrayLength;
            startLocation = -1;

            while ((startLocation = Array.IndexOf(caller, startValue, startLocation + 1)) >= 0)
            {
                if (startLocation > searchBoundary)
                    break;

                if (caller[startLocation + endOffset] == endValue)
                {
                    for (j = 1; j < endOffset && caller[startLocation + j] == array[j]; j++) { }

                    if (j == endOffset)
                    {
                        result = startLocation;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = Array.IndexOf(caller, startValue);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Also the version of the original posters code I used for test purposes:

```
    public static int IndexOf(this byte[] AllBytes, int index, byte[] searchByteArray)
    {
        for (int i = index; i <= AllBytes.Length - 1 - searchByteArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= searchByteArray.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (AllBytes[i + j] == searchByteArray[j])
                {
                    if (j + 1 == searchByteArray.Length)
                        return i;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

And finally my code which tests the functions:

```
    private static void TestContains()
    {
        bool copyContained;
        int result, offset;
        byte[] containedValue, containingValue;
        Random rng;
        Stopwatch watch1, watch2;
        List<Tuple<byte[], byte[], bool, int>> testList;

        testList = new();
        watch1 = new();
        watch2 = new();
        rng = new();

        for (int j = 0; j < 120; j++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine($"Test number {j:#,0} in progress...");

            for (int i = 32; i < 40000; i++)
            {
                offset = 0;
                copyContained = rng.Next(0, 1000) != 0;

                containingValue = new byte[i];
                rng.NextBytes(containingValue);

                containedValue = new byte[rng.Next(8, i)];

                if (copyContained)
                {
                    offset = rng.Next(0, i - containedValue.Length);
                    rng.NextBytes(containedValue);
                    Array.Copy(containedValue, 0, containingValue, offset, containedValue.Length);
                }
                testList.Add(new Tuple<byte[], byte[], bool, int>(containingValue, containedValue, copyContained, offset));
            }
            
            foreach (var testCase in testList)
            {
                watch1.Start();
                result = testCase.Item1.Contains(testCase.Item2);
                watch1.Stop();
                watch2.Start();
                testCase.Item1.IndexOf(0, testCase.Item2);
                watch2.Stop();

                if ((testCase.Item1.Length == 0 && result != -1) ||
                    (testCase.Item2.Length == 0 && result != -1) ||
                    (testCase.Item3 && result != testCase.Item4) ||
                    (!testCase.Item3 && result != -1))
                    Debugger.Break();
            }
            testList.Clear();
            //CollectGarbage(0);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(
            "\r\n\r\n" + $@"Comparison duration (using Contains): {watch1.Elapsed:hh\:mm\:ss\.ff}" + "\r\n" +
            "\r\n" + $@"Comparison duration (using Contains2): {watch2.Elapsed:hh\:mm\:ss\.ff}" + "\r\n" +
            "\r\n" + $@"Speed differential: {(watch1.Elapsed > watch2.Elapsed ? $"Contains2 is {((double)watch1.ElapsedTicks / watch2.ElapsedTicks - 1) * 100:#.00}%" : $"Contains is {((double)watch2.ElapsedTicks / watch1.ElapsedTicks - 1) * 100:#.00}%")} faster." +
            "\r\n\r\n\r\n Press enter to continue.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

While a 100% improvement isn't going to make the difference in some cases, it's an improvement nonetheless and a pretty significant one.  On the old desktop I am testing this on, a Core i5-4570, I can find the position of the array I am searching for in a 1 GB array in less than a second.  I didn't specifically test large arrays as you can see because my use case is for smaller arrays, less than 65 KB.